# PHP looping through an array, not displaying the first records

Tags: php, arrays

This is a question concerning a solutions provided by @Blaatpraat which solved that part of my issue.

I now have an array which contains:

```
Array ( [NXLHR01011474021550] =>  
Array ( [UniqueID] => NXLHR01011474021550 [Room] => 0101 [AuditBy] => navexdemo2 [AuditDate] => 2016-09-16 11:26:00 [SeqID] => SeqID1306 [Status] => 1 [WaterHot] => 67.0 [WaterCold] => 18.0 )  
[NXLHR01021474021587] => 
Array ( [UniqueID] => NXLHR01021474021587 [Room] => 0102 [AuditBy] => navexdemo2 [AuditDate] => 2016-09-16 11:26:00 [SeqID] => SeqID1306 [Status] => 0 [WaterHot] => 65.0 [WaterCold] => 21.0 )
)
```

I am now tring to display each record in the array row by row.

My code is;

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
echo $array[$row['UniqueID']]['Room']."\n";
echo $array[$row['UniqueID']]['AuditBy']."\n";
echo $array[$row['UniqueID']]['WaterHot']."\n";
echo $array[$row['UniqueID']]['WaterCold']."\n";
}
```

But the result is:
    "0102 navexdemo2 65.0 21.0"
    "0102 navexdemo2 65.0 21.0"
the same record twice.

Does anyone know why the first record in the array is not displayed.

I have had a lot of help from members and I was trying to avoid asking for help but I have tried so many ways to get this to work without success.

Again, I thank you for your time.

Comment: `$row['UniqueID']` is __always the same__

Comment: @u_mulder hi, when you say "$row['UniqueID'] is always the same" are you asking if it is or are you saying it always will be. The "UniqueID changes depending on the record.

Comment: Depending on what record? In your `foreach` it is __always the same__.

Comment: @u_mulder Each record has a UniqueID, my example array only contains two records. I am writingthe "foreach" statement correctly?

Comment: `UniqueID` is a key if `$item`, not `$row`.

Comment: Use `$item` instead of `$row` inside the loop, is that I think what @u_mulder is saying.

Comment: @jedifans That works. u_mulder thanks for your input. Many eyes make thing work. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be what you were going for?

```
<?php

    $array = [
        'NXLHR01011474021550'  => [
            'UniqueID'  => 'NXLHR01011474021550',
            'Room'      => '0101',
            'AuditBy'   => 'navexdemo2',
            'AuditDate' => '2016-09-16 11:26:00',
            'SeqID'     => 'SeqID1306',
            'Status'    => 1,
            'WaterHot'  => 67.0,
            'WaterCold' => 18.0,
        ],

        'NXLHR01021474021587'  => [
            'UniqueID'  => 'NXLHR01021474021587',
            'Room'      => '0102',
            'AuditBy'   => 'navexdemo2',
            'AuditDate' => '2016-09-16 11:26:00',
            'SeqID'     => 'SeqID1306',
            'Status'    => 0,
            'WaterHot'  => 65.0,
            'WaterCold' => 21.0,
        ],
    ];

    foreach($array as $uKey=>$arrData){     
        echo $arrData['Room']."\n";
        echo $arrData['AuditBy']."\n";
        echo $arrData['WaterHot']."\n";
        echo $arrData['WaterCold']."\n";

    }
```

> To **visualise the Output a little Clearer**, you could take this route:

```
<?php

    $dataList   = "<ul>" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach($array as $uKey=>$arrData){
        $sp        = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        $dataList .= "<li><h3>Unique ID: {$uKey}</h3></li>"                             . PHP_EOL;
        $dataList .= "<li><strong>Room: </strong>{$sp}{$arrData['Room']}</li>"          . PHP_EOL;
        $dataList .= "<li><strong>AuditBy: </strong>{$sp}{$arrData['AuditBy']}</li>"    . PHP_EOL;
        $dataList .= "<li><strong>WaterHot: </strong>{$sp}{$arrData['WaterHot']}</li>"  . PHP_EOL;
        $dataList .= "<li><strong>WaterCold: </strong>{$sp}{$arrData['WaterCold']}</li>". PHP_EOL;
    }
    $dataList .= "</ul>";

    echo $dataList;
```

The `echo $dataList` above would produce something like:

- #### Unique ID: NXLHR01011474021550
- **Room:**              0101
- **AuditBy:**          navexdemo2
- **WaterHot:**        67
- **WaterCold:**     18
- #### Unique ID: NXLHR01021474021587
- **Room:**             0102
- **AuditBy:**         navexdemo2
- **WaterHot:**       65
- **WaterCold:**     21

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    echo $item[$row['UniqueID']]['Room']."\n";
    echo $item[$row['UniqueID']]['AuditBy']."\n";
   echo $item[$row['UniqueID']]['WaterHot']."\n";
   echo $item[$row['UniqueID']]['WaterCold']."\n";
}
```

Comment: I used 
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    echo $item['Room']."\n";
    echo $item['AuditBy']."\n";
   echo $item['WaterHot']."\n";
   echo $item['WaterCold']."\n";
}
and wored just as I needed.

Comment: Cool.. happy coding :)